# How to add data section to Netlify CMS?

Tags: hugo, netlify-cms, decap-cms

I have a Hugo-based site and a couple of `partials` on the main page that I would like to add as parts of CMS. The partials are made of HTML layout and YAML in the data section. How can I expose this information to CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but assuming that your partials are driven by that YAML data, you can look at the [file collection type](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/collection-types/#file-collections) to manage it.

Here's an example of what your `config.yml` file might look like:

```yaml
collections:
  - label: "Settings"
    name: "settings"
    files:
      - label: "Partials"
        name: "partials"
        file: "data/partials.yml"
        fields:
          - label: "List of partials"
            name: "partials_list"
            widget: "list"
            fields:
              - {label: "Name", name: "name", widget: "string"}
              - {label: "Partial type", name: "type", widget: "select", options: ["typeA", "typeB", "typeC"] }
```